# How to expand all children of a Stack that includes a CustomPainter in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-custompainter, flutter-responsive-layout

Let's say in Flutter we have a Stack that contains:

1. A CustomPainter with size of Size.infinite
2. Any other widget that is not a Custom Painter (*that we also want to fill all available space exactly the same way that the custom painter does*)

In this example, I'm using an Icon for item 2:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Icon(Icons.star),
            CustomPaint(
                painter: MyCustomPainter(percentTimeElapsed: 0.5),
                size: Size.infinite)
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Now, obviously, we don't get the desired result yet -- the custom painter is "expanded" *but the icon is not*.

But I have tried all the following with no luck:

- Wrapping the Icon with Expanded (causes exception)
- Wrapping the Stack widget with Expanded (causes exception)
- Defining the size of the Icon to be Size.infinite (will not build because size param expects a double)
- Using *fit: StackFit.expand* as a parameter for the Stack, but this just seems to center the Icon and doesn't change it's size.

Comment: Can you include `Expanded`'s parent widgets?

Comment: `fit: StackFit.expand` + `FittedBox(child: Icon(Icons.star)),`

Comment: pskink, copy and paste to answer to collect your winnings.

Comment: you are welcome to write a self answer... ;-)